# How to add the OnShareTargetActivated() method manually in a windows 8 C# blank application?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have created a Windows8 blank xaml application.And now i want to make this application as a Share Target.I have followed the instructions at below link and able to make it as a Target app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh973053

But where do i add the following method (OnShareTargetActivated) in my blank xaml application ?When i manually add this method in mainpage.xaml.cs , it shows the errors"

"Project.MainPage.OnShareTargetActivated(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs)' is a new virtual member in sealed class "

"Project.MainPage.OnShareTargetActivated(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override "

```
 protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
 {
   // Code to handle activation goes here. 
}
```

Comment: Did you check the sample app? [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782)

Comment: I got the answer.It needs to be added to app.xaml.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

It goes in the class that inherits from Windows.UI.Xaml.Application. Typically App.cs.

E.g.

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    //...

    protected override void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var rootFrame = new Frame();
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.ShareOperation);
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```